# How do I limit my PL/SQL query to search only relevant tables?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-table

I'm trying to write a PL/SQL script that searches the entire database for a string and report the tables and columns it finds it in. It looks like this:

```
DECLARE
  ncount NUMBER;
  vwhere VARCHAR2(1000) := '';
  vsearchstr VARCHAR2(1000) := 'search string here';
  vresult VARCHAR2(10000) := 'result: ';
  vtab VARCHAR2(1000) := '';
  vcol VARCHAR2(1000) := '';
BEGIN
  FOR k IN (SELECT a.table_name, a.column_name FROM all_tab_columns a WHERE a.data_type LIKE '%VARCHAR%')
  LOOP
    vtab := k.table_name;
    vcol := k.column_name;
    vwhere := ' where ' || vcolumnname || ' = :vsearchstr ';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(1) from ' || vtab || vwhere INTO ncount USING vsearctstr;
    IF (ncount > 0)
    THEN
      vresult := CONCAT(vresult, vcol || ' ' || vtab || ', ');
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  
  IF (LENGTH(vresult) > 1)
  THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(vresult);
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('not found');
  END IF;
END;
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

[image]

It is essentially saying it doesn't recognize the table `vtab` in the line `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(1) from ' || vtab || vwhere INTO ncount USING vsearctstr`.

So in order to see which table it's complaining about, I added the following exception block to the end of the script:

```
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
    BEGIN
      dbms_output.put_line('exception: ' || vtab);
    END;
```

It tells me the table name is `IND$`.

I'm not sure what this table (or view) is and it doesn't look relevant anyway.

So my question is two fold: 1) If it is fetching IND$ in the FOR loop from k.table_name (which in turn is from all_tab_columns), why does it say it doesn't exist in the select query? 2) I'm not sure what IND$ is but I'm pretty sure I don't need to search it; So is there a way to limit my search to only relevant tables (not views)? By 'relevant', I mean tables that we created to store data for our application (as opposed to system tables or user tables, etc.).

Thanks very much.

Comment: _tables that we created to store data for our application_ How do you identify those tables? Are they all in the same schema? Do they use a particular naming pattern? If there aren't a lot of them, maybe you can hard code them using the IN operator, i.e. `where TABLE_NAME in (...)`

Comment: When performing your `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement, instead of selecting from `TABLE_NAME` you should select from `SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME` to search for data in tables that are not in your current schema.

Comment: PL/SQL is for code, SQL is for queries. There's no such thing as a PL/SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

`all_tab_columns` lists columns in all tables that your current schema has access to.  In general, if you're going to use ALL_... views to build dynamic SQL, you should incorporate the `OWNER` column as well since it may return rows for tables in other schemas.

If you really only want to consider tables in your current schema, use  `user_tab_columns` instead.

If you want to get more, or less, particular than that about which tables are 'relevant', then you'll probably need to hardcode specific rules into your query.

FYI: `IND$` is part of the Oracle data dictionary and is in the SYS schema. (Although, it's always possible someone has created a table with that name in some other schema.)  It's unusual that your application schema would have direct access to this.

Comment: "If you really only want to consider tables in your current schema, use `user_tab_columns` instead." This seems to give me only tables that I created, not all tables that I have access to.

Comment: @gib65 Yes, exactly. `user...`  views report on objects you own, and `all...` views report on all objects you have access to.

Comment: Ah, understood.

Answer (score 1):

If you know *how* to skip tables you don't want, do it - you might filter by `OWNER`, maybe table name, etc.

If you don't want to bother, include inner `begin-exception-end` block into the loop so that it skips errors (either silently, or display errors, or store them into some table). Here's one option:

```
DECLARE
  ncount NUMBER;
  vwhere VARCHAR2(1000) := '';
  vsearchstr VARCHAR2(1000) := 'search string here';
  vresult VARCHAR2(10000) := 'result: ';
  vtab VARCHAR2(1000) := '';
  vcol VARCHAR2(1000) := '';
BEGIN
  FOR k IN (SELECT a.table_name, a.column_name FROM all_tab_columns a WHERE a.data_type LIKE '%VARCHAR%')
  LOOP
  BEGIN
    vtab := k.table_name;
    vcol := k.column_name;
    vwhere := ' where ' || vcolumnname || ' = :vsearchstr ';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(1) from ' || vtab || vwhere INTO ncount USING vsearctstr;
    IF (ncount > 0)
    THEN
      vresult := CONCAT(vresult, vcol || ' ' || vtab || ', ');
    END IF;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vtab ||': '|| sqlerrm);
  END;
  END LOOP;
  
  IF (LENGTH(vresult) > 1)
  THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(vresult);
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('not found');
  END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

- Also get the `owner` from `all_tab_columns`
- Use quoted identifiers around the `owner`, `table_name` and `column_name` so that the query does not fail for identifiers in different cases or with special characters.
- Handle errors (i.e. when you do not have the permissions to `SELECT` from a table).

To make it faster, you can:

- Filter the columns to only those that are long enough to contain the search string.

You can do that using:

```sql
DECLARE
  ncount NUMBER;
  vsearchstr VARCHAR2(1000) := 'search string here';
  vresult VARCHAR2(10000);
BEGIN
  FOR k IN (SELECT owner,
                   table_name,
                   column_name
            FROM   all_tab_columns
            WHERE  data_type LIKE '%VARCHAR%'
            AND    data_length >= LENGTH(vsearchstr))
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
         'select count(1)
          from   "' || k.owner || '"."' || k.table_name || '"
          where  "' || k.column_name || '" = :1'
        INTO  ncount
        USING vsearchstr;

      IF (ncount > 0)
      THEN
        vresult := vresult || ','
                   || k.owner || '.' || k.table_name || '.' || k.column_name;
      END IF;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        NULL;
    END;
  END LOOP;
  
  IF (LENGTH(vresult) > 1)
  THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(vresult);
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('not found');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=39d317dca7f6f2f0a7f4656fa371237e)*

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final query (which works):

```
DECLARE
  ncount NUMBER;
  vwhere VARCHAR2(1000) := '';
  vsearchstr VARCHAR2(1000) := '%your string here%';
  vresult VARCHAR2(10000) := '';
  vtab VARCHAR2(1000) := '';
  vcol VARCHAR2(1000) := '';
BEGIN
  FOR k IN (SELECT table_name, column_name
              FROM all_tab_columns
             WHERE data_type LIKE '%VARCHAR%'
               AND data_length >= LENGTH(vsearchstr)
               AND table_name NOT IN (SELECT view_name FROM all_views))
  LOOP
  BEGIN
    vtab := k.table_name;
    vcol := k.column_name;
    vwhere := ' where ' || vcol || ' like :vsearchstr ';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(1) from OWNER.' || vtab || vwhere INTO ncount USING vsearchstr;
    IF (ncount > 0)
    THEN
      vresult := CONCAT(vresult, 'table: ' || vtab || ', column: ' || vcol || chr(13) || chr(10));
    END IF;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
    END;
  END LOOP;

  IF (LENGTH(vresult) > 0)
  THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(vresult);
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('string not found');
  END IF;
END;
```

I took Littlefoot's advice and added an exception block to catch the exception when the table is not found and just continue with the loop. I also took MT0's advice and checked the length of the column in the select query. I also included the owner in the select query.

This works. Thanks to everyone who gave their advice.